# Dates are not updating through sql code in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to update serial.Issuedate getting from form but its giving syntax error.
Please help me how can I correct this error.
My code is below:

```
Private Sub Command30_Click()

Set serialrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("serial")
Dim Idate As Date
Dim Itodo As String
Idate = Me.IssuedDate.Value
Itodo = Me.IssuedToDO.Value

Dim issueqry As String
issueqry = "UPDATE serial " _
& " set serial.IssueToDO =  '" & Itodo & "'" _
& " serial.issuedate = (#" & Format(Idate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#)" _
& " WHERE (((serial.id) Between 1 And 10)) "

DoCmd.RunSQL issueqry

MsgBox ("Issued Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know enough about VBA but `Format` function probably does not need `\/`. You might be able to write `Format(Idate, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Answer (score 1):

When you update more than one field, you must include a comma between the  field expressions like this ...

```vb
SET [field name] = "foo", [another field] = 17
                        ^
                       here
```

So try your code like this ...

```vb
issueqry = "UPDATE serial " _
& " set serial.IssueToDO = '" & Itodo & "'," _
& " serial.issuedate = #" & Format(Idate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#" _
& " WHERE serial.id Between 1 And 10"
```

Also give yourself an opportunity to inspect the string the code built ...

```vb
Debug.Print issueqry
```

You can view the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there.